# Change color of cells based on value from another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, casting

I m trying to change color of cells based on value fron another sheets

```
Sub ColoredOutlier()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, x As Integer

    For i = 1 To 50

        For j = 2 To 23

            If IsEmpty(Worksheets("outlier_index").Cells(i, j)) Then Exit For

            x = Worksheets("outlier_index").Cells(i, j).Value

            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(x+1, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3  

        Next j   

   Next i  

End Sub
```

When ı run these codes above I m getting "type mismatch" error becasue of

> x = Worksheets("outlier_index").Cells(i, j).Value

Could anyone help me about solve my problem?

Comment: The type mismatch may be telling you that the value of outlier_index cell at (i, j) is not an integer. Possibly try logging the value of the cell first. Something like: ```For i, for j, val = Worksheets("outlier_index").cells(i,j).value Debug.Print "Value at i=", i, " and j=", j, " is ", val ``` My apologies, I don't have excel on this comp to test for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested above the type mismatch error can occur when the value of the cell is not an integer.

You could easily modify your code to skip cells containing strings:

```
If IsEmpty(Worksheets("outlier_index").Cells(i, j)) Or Not _ 
IsNumeric(Worksheets("outlier_index").Cells(i, j)) Then Exit For
```

You might need to amend it a little further if you have non-integer numbers in your sheet too.

Answer (score 1):

X should be a string. The value from a cell will be stored as String. And x should not be used here.

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, x).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

It should be

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

All together:

```
Sub ColoredOutlier()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, x As String

For i = 1 To 50

    For j = 2 To 23

        If IsEmpty(Worksheets("outlier_index").Cells(i, j)) Then Exit For

        x = Worksheets("outlier_index").Cells(i, j).Value
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: but I need to get value of " x" as a integer and then change the color of another sheet's cells based on "x"

Comment: I don't get you
X is the value of a cell. You want to use that value for something?

Comment: I mean I need to get value of "Worksheets("outlier_index").Cells(i, j).Value" as integer which ı called it "x "and I know "x" is a row nuber of my outliers matrix.In the end I want to use x to change color of row data

Comment: x is not row number. i is your row number and j is the column number